# attach events to a dynamic editable=true list

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the next list

```
<ul contenteditable="true">
  <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

And i used the next script

```
$(document).on('paste','[contenteditable="true"]', function (e) {
  //my actions to take
});
```

It works well with a pre loaded list,when i hit enter it creates a new `<li>` element (and thats ok) but dosent work with the new list element

Answer (score -1):

Use `.delegate` instead of `.on`

jQuery documentation on `.on`

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

careful, the `.on` signature is different from the one `.delegate` uses!
see https://api.jquery.com/delegate/ for more details.

Comment: It dosent work, now the code looks like 
  $(document).delegate('[contenteditable="true"]','paste', function (e) {
     //my actions to take  
});